# How do I add new user data inside a class ArrayList

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Sorry if I'm not explaining this correctly, but how would I add new contact information into.

I'm working on a personal project and trying to add data into an arraylist list. I created  input for the user to enter the information but how do I go about adding the information into the array list?

ArrayList contactLists = new ArrayList<>();

Main Class:

```
package com.ContactList;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    ArrayList<ContactList> contactLists = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayMen();
    }


    public static void displayMen() {

        do {

            System.out.println("Please choose from the following selection \n press 2 add a business contact \n press 2 to a personal contact \n press 3 to display your contact list");

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int select = sc.nextInt();

            switch (select) {
                case 1:
                    //use this to add a business contact
                    // System.out.println("This is a test ot see the code is working");
                    addContact();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //use this to add a personal contact

                    break;
                case 3:
                    //allow the user to display the contact information
                    break;
                case 4:
                    //this is to quit the program
            }

        } while (true);
    }

    public static void addContact() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the user first name");
        String fNmae = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the user last name");
        String lName = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the user address");
        String address = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the user phoneNumber");
        String phoneNumber = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the user email");
        String email = sc.next();
        String data = (lName + lName + address + phoneNumber + email);





    }


}
```

ContactList Class:

```
package com.ContactList;

public class ContactList {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String address;
    String phoneNumber;
    String email;

    public void contactList(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String phoneNumber, String email){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
    }


    //Getter Methods
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public int getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

Business Contact class:

```
package com.ContactList;

public class BusinessContact extends ContactList{

    String jobTitle;
    String organization;


    public void businessContact(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String phoneNumber, String email) {
        super.contactList(firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber, email);
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
        this.organization = organization;
    }
}
```

PersonalContact class:

```
public class PersonalContact extends ContactList{

    int dateOfBirth;


    public void PersonalContact(String firstName, String lastName, String address, int phoneNumber, String email, int dateOfBirth) {
        super.contactList(firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber, email);

        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public int getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: `ContactList` class should be named `Contact`.  Descriptive naming will make your code easier to comprehend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can just create a new `PersonalContact`/`BusinessContact`  object inside your `addContact()`, initialized with the data you just got from the user, and add that to the end of the ArrayList using the `add()` method.

For `BusinessContact`, the job title and organization fields are missing from the constructor parameter list, so you will need to add those.

For `PersonalContact`, you've chosen to store the phoneNumber and dateOfBirth fields as integers, so you'll need to use the appropriate `Scanner` methods to get that data and cast it appropriately.

Perhaps you should also indicate to the `addContact` method whether the contact will be a `BusinessContact` or a `PersonalContact` so you know what type of object to construct at the end:

`contactLists.add(new BusinessContact(fName, lName, address, phoneNumber, email, jobTitle, organization);`

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code from OOP perspective. But tring dirrectlly to answer your question you have to do 2 things:

1. In **ContactList** class you are missing all the **SETTERs** for the class private fields (which right now are default, you should make them private). Those could help you if you want to change any values related to these fields. This will allow you to set a value for each of the class atributes, which brings us to the next thing.
2. In **Main** class at the line:

> String data = (lName + lName + address + phoneNumber + email);

You should create a new ClientList object via it's constructor and populate it's attributes with the values that you have just read from the user:

```
contactLists.add(new ContactList(fName, lName, address, phoneNumber, email));
```